# Error trying to install NVIDIA OPTIMUS in Recovery Mode

Tags: software-installation, nvidia-optimus, recovery-mode

When I try to install NVIDIA OPTIMUS in Recovery Mode, I run:

```
sudo sh path/to/NVIDIA....run
```

And I get this error:

```
unable to create temporary files in /tmp
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The file systems are mounted read-only in Recovery Mode. Try this to remount as read/write:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Then re-run the installation program.